# Permitir acentos en inputs

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombre" required>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery('#nombre').keypress(function(tecla){
        if((tecla.charCode < 97 || tecla.charCode > 122) && (tecla.charCode < 65 || tecla.charCode > 90) && (tecla.charCode != 45) && (tecla.charCode != 32))
    return false;
    });
</script>
```

Lo que quiero conseguir es que bloquee todos los caracteres especiales (**@!{}[]*+...**) haciendo excepción a las tildes. Si hay un usuario que se llame (**José**) no va a poder hacer la tilde; Lo que necesito es que bloquee todos los caracteres exceptuando los acentos (**tildes**)

Answer (score 1):

Es mas facil tener una lista de caracteres especiales prohibidos:

```js
var format = /[ `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/;
var tecla;
tecla = "@"; document.write(tecla + " - " + !format.test(tecla) + "<br>");
tecla = "e"; document.write(tecla + " - " + !format.test(tecla) + "<br>");
tecla = "é"; document.write(tecla + " - " + !format.test(tecla) + "<br>");
```

Entonces

```
<script>
    jQuery('#nombre').keypress(function(tecla){
        var format = /[ `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/;
        return !format.test(tecla);
    });
</script>
```

`format` es una [expresión regular](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Expresiones_regulares_en_javascript) que cumple con caracteres especiales. `format.test(tecla) === true` significa que `tecla` contiene un caracter especial y que debemos bloquear el evento de `keypress`

Comment: Me podría indicar como puedo implementarlo en mi codigo, por favor; soy muy nuevo en js / jq

Comment: He editado mi publicación